# How can I tell a livestream from a video in youtube uploads playlist

Tags: youtube-data-api

I call the youtube data api (v3) to get a list of my user's uploads. I use an oauth token specifically so that I can get both public and unlisted videos. This all works fine. Recently I am seeing a live stream included in playlist position 0. This seems to be a general live stream for the channel, but it has a unique_id just as any other video would and is 'public'. Here is the data (identifying information redacted) for the playlist item

```
kind: youtube#playlistItem
etag: '"XXXXX"'
id: XXXXX
snippet:
  publishedAt: '2015-08-26T17:22:10.000Z'
  channelId: XXXX
  title: XXXXX Live Stream
  description: ''
  thumbnails: <removed for brevity>
  channelTitle: XXXXX
  playlistId: UUXXXXX
  position: 0
  resourceId:
    kind: youtube#video
    videoId: XXXXX
status:
  privacyStatus: public
```

I need a way to exclude this channel live stream (and live streams generally) but there is nothing in the playlist item that indicates the status.

I tried pulling the corresponding video data but it says the entry is not a live broadcast and no liveStreamingDetails part is returned

```
data = YoutubeApiV3.instance.video_list({ 'id' => unique_id, 'part' =>'snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,liveStreamingDetails' })

kind: youtube#videoListResponse
etag: '"XXXXXX"'
pageInfo:
  totalResults: 1
  resultsPerPage: 1
items:
  kind: youtube#video
  etag: '"XXXXXX"'
  id: XXXXX
  snippet:
    publishedAt: '2015-08-26T17:22:10.000Z'
    channelId: XXXXXX
    title: XXXXXX Live Stream
    description: ''
    thumbnails: <removed for brevity>
    channelTitle: XXXX
    categoryId: '22'
    liveBroadcastContent: none
    localized:
      title: XXXX Live Stream
      description: ''
    contentDetails:
      duration: PT0S
      dimension: 2d
      definition: sd
      caption: 'false'
      licensedContent: false
      regionRestriction: <omitted>
  status:
    uploadStatus: uploaded
    privacyStatus: public
    license: youtube
    embeddable: true
    publicStatsViewable: true
  statistics:
    viewCount: '0'
    likeCount: '0'
    dislikeCount: '0'
    favoriteCount: '0'
    commentCount: '0'
```

What can I do here to figure out this is a live stream? Is there some other part I can check? Is this a bug? Shouldn't this be filterable on playlistItems list? Not every channel has this live stream and I really don't want test the video title as that can be changed.

Comment: Looking at the video record again, I see snippet.contentDetails.duration shows a duration of of 0s, which is probably a better test than video title.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned when using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with `part=liveStreamingDetails`, no `liveStreamingDetails` entry is returned for videos and a `liveStreamingDetails` is returned for livestreams. You can distinguish videos and livestreams that way.

Comment: yeah, but the costs are very high if you are processing hundreds of videos

Comment: Are you aware that you can [provide up to 50](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#maxResults) [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id)s by request?